# Share laptop WIFI to a router using network sharing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have been trying to get this to work for a while. I want to share my laptop's connection, connected to a wpa2-entreprise network on campus. I want it to connect to a switch and connect an access point to have my own wireless network in my room for my xbox.

I can successfully share my laptop connection to one device using wired connection. Is there a way to share my connection and create my own "subnetwork"? My budget for this is anywhere between 10-500$.

School network > Laptop > switch > router > other devices

Perhaps I need different equipment?

Comment: How often does the wpa2 enterprise key change?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do: school network > router > switch > laptop. I believe that is a conventional setup. Many people don't understand the purpose of a network is to bridge two networks. You can't have your laptop on one side of the router and the switch on the other. The router should be as far up the stack as possible. If you can only get a wireless connection, your switch should still be underneath the router

Comment: @JohnyVegas it never changes, I have an SSID and password assigned to me

Comment: Is there a router that support wpa2-entreprise and could then let every device connect and use a single IP when talking back to school network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using windows go into the network and sharing center and click change adapter settings to get this window.
[image]

Then right click on your Wifi connection and tick **Allow other network users to connect through this computers internet connection** in the sharing tab. Select the Ethernet port on your laptop.

[image]

Then just connect a wireless router [such as this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TL-WR841N-300Mbps-Wireless-Router/dp/B001FWYGJS/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1471376809&sr=8-2&keywords=wireless+router) to the ethernet port and make sure DHCP is disabled and give it a static IP in the router settings.